# How to show diff. number of tabs on tabbar on diff. screen in IOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

In my IOS app, I want to show slider Menu with tabbar, I am done with slider menu, 
But I am facing difficulty to show tabbar in my app,

1.Can we show tabbar in app which have slider menu? if yes, How can I implement it?

2.How to show diff. number of tabs on diff screen, (like screen "A" has 3 tabs in tabbar while screen "B" have 5 tabs in tabbar)

I am using objective-C

Right now i have done With this (slider menu) 
[image]

and I want to achieve this (tabbar with slider menu)

[image]

Comment: do you have enough reputation to add an image or screenshot of what your app currently looks like and what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sure I'll update soon

Comment: Are you using a library for the slide menu? For the different number of tabs for a specific page. You will have to set page B as a new TabBarController with different ViewControllers.

Comment: thanks, I am not using any library